# CSS Animation on hover out

Tags: javascript, css, animation, opacity

I'm trying to get an element to animate using CSS when hovering out of an area.
(I'm not familiar with how to do this in javascript)

I've done the hover animation using the hover pseudo element and keyframe animations.
I'm trying to animate opacity on :hover and hover out.

I've got the :hover animation ok, but I want the animate the hover out effect.
Is there a way to do this with CSS3? I've tried a few things, but no luck.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="post-header">    
  <h2 class="post-title">Header 
    <em>- Sub Header -</em>
  </h2>         
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.post-header {
background: rgba(17,17,17,0.35);
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-right: 100px;
}

/*Fading out*/
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}

h2.post-title em{
    display: none;
    -webkit-animation: fadeout 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: fadeout 1.2s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeout 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

/*Fading in*/
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

a.post-header:hover em {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: fadein 1.2s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadein 1.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

See the fiddle below

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabs999/nxvohneh/19/)

Thanks!

Comment: in CSS, there is no `mouseleave` statement to represent hover out, it just returns to the default state defined in CSS. you'll need to use JS if you want that value to be different after hovering out.

Comment: Isn't there a way to reverse the animation when the :hover pseudo element isn't active anymore?

Comment: ok you want to reverse the CSS animation on hover out? yes it is possible, basically you need to incorporate `transition-delay` in your CSS. here is a good resource, which they use for menus => http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

Comment: you can also consider adding some js to implement this effect, like here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/bl-fade-in-out-css3.htm#fadingout

Comment: sorry, i just noticed you were using CSS animations instead of transitions. what you want can totally be done with transitions, animations are far more difficult, if even possible. that said, you are just doing opacity, so you should be using transitions anyway.

Comment: ok, so I need to use transitions instead of keyframe animations? I'll rewrite and respond tomorrow (I'm in the UK). Thanks for the links @PlantTheIdea and shershen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use CSS Transitions instead of animations.

Then you can set it as follows:

```
h2.post-title em{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}

a.post-header:hover em {
    opacity: 1;
}
```